# combine text from a variable number of cells into 1 cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a parsing spreadsheet to format text.  The text can vary by several cells and several sections might need to be done back to back.

I have an example of text: (I have added cell number to each line due to word wrap)

```
b16:Darkheart Hive Aura. All other friendly shrill within 60 feet learn the Hive Offering reaction.

b17: False Appearance. While the shrill remains motionless, it is indistinguishable from a tangle of vines.

b18: Spellcasting. The shrill's spellcasting ability is Intelligence (spell save DC 16, +7 to hit with spell attacks), and is considered an 11th level spellcaster. The shrill can innately cast the following spells, requiring no material components:

b19: At Will: Druidcraft, Thorn Whip, Booming Blade
b20: 5/day each: Entangle, Healing Word (3rd level)
b21: 3/day each: Spike Growth
b22: 1/day each: Contagion
b23: Actions
b24: Talon. Melee Weapon Attack: +8 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit 18 (3d8 + 6) slashing damage.

b25: Reactions
b26: Hive Offering. When another shrill within 30 feet is being damaged by another creature. The shrill can reduce its HP to 0. Up to six shrill within 30 feet, including the one being damaged, regain hit points equal to 2d4 + 1 for each shrill within 30 feet. The shrill crumbles to ash and dies.

b27: Legendary Actions
b28: The shrill can take 3 legendary actions, choosing from the options below. Only one legendary action can be used at a time and only at the end of another creature's turn. The shrill regains spent legendary actions at the start of its turn.

b29: Move. The shrill moves up to its speed without provoking opportunity attacks.

b30: Cantrip. The shrill casts a cantrip.

b31: Healing Word (Costs 2 Actions). The shrill casts the Healing Word spell.
```

I need to combine all the information from spellcasting to before reactions and move it to a single new cell. Along with this, I need to move each line from Darkheart to before actions to cells I17 to I21, then take line beneath reactions and put in cell I30.  The same for the line after actions in cells i23 to i29.  The lines beneath Legendary actions into cells I31 to I34

have the code to move it to the other spells but I am not sure how to combine or find a way to deal with there are more or less under each area.  If there are more lines between cells b23 and b25

Comment: you can combine cell contents with concatenate() or even & , like =A1&B1

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]for guidance on posting questions we can answer and are useful to others with similar issues

Comment: The problem is I might have to combine 3 cells for this entry and 4 for the next and have only 1 the third..  they may also start at b16 this time but might start at b20 the next.  that actual concatenate is not the issue, it is taking into consideration all of the other variables

Comment: Use the `Range.Find` method to determine the defining rows of the range you need to concatenate.

Comment: I can see that a little bit for basic information but not how to do that. the spellcasting for this one has 5 line but the next might only have 3 lines

Comment: I was able to get it to select the cell under the unneeded header with Set Action_first = Range("b1:b45").Find(Action_Start).Offset(1, 0) but I don't know how to repeat it without adding multiple copies with if then to check for the next header multiple times.